# Как изменить значение hardwareConcurrency?

Tags: javascript, firefox

В `navigator` есть значение как `hardwareConcurrency` - кол-во ядер CPU. Как его изменить через `about:config`? Пробовал по всякому

`general.hardwareConcurrency.override` никак не работает.

Этим же способом можно изменить useragent, oscpu и т.д. но не `hardwareConcurrency` есть способ как это сделать?

Comment: Сдается мне, тут мы видим типичную [проблему XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/). Какую задачу Вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @Yaant просто нужно изменить это значение, к примеру `useragent` браузера можно изменить вот так `general.useragent.override` - Это я о Firefox

Comment: Изменить зачем? Просто чтобы было?

Comment: нет, не просто, изменить нужно для кое чего, но я думаю это уже моё личное дело зачем мне это)

Comment: В общем-то никак не изменить, ибо `The NavigatorConcurrentHardware.hardwareConcurrency read-only property returns the number of logical processors available to run threads on the user's computer`, Слова `read-only property` как бы намекают. Впрочем, наверно можно пропатчить операционную систему, чтобы она возвращала другое значение на соответствующий запрос FireFox'а.

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: Хотя я не совсем прав, ибо про useragent тоже сказано, что это read-only property, однако оно меняется через about:config. Но этот момент отражен в документации. Поскольку тут такого не сказано, видимо, возможность изменить это значение разработчиками действительно не предусмотрена.

Comment: @emtecif если не секрет, зачем вам понадобилось это свойство менять?

Answer (score 1):

Он нормально меняется путем подмены в `window.navigator.hardwareConcurrency`

Comment: Дополните ваш ответ более подробной информацией.

Answer (score 1):

можно подменить следующим образом:

```
Object.defineProperties(navigator, {
            hardwareConcurrency: {
                value: %YOUR_VALUE%,
                configurable: false,
                enumerable: true,
                writable: false
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно уменьшить значение, возвращаемое navigator.hardwareConcurrency, если оно было больше единицы. Для этого через about:config меняете значение параметра dom.maxHardwareConcurrency с 16 (по умолчанию) на 1 и перезапускаете Firefox. Проверено в FF52/WinXP на двух ядрах.